# How to change the default notification sound by another sound which are already installed on the android smartphone

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I want my app not should play the default notification sound but I want to play any other sound that is installed on Android smartphones.
I know that all other notification sounds can be changed on Android smartphones under App settings / Notification Categories.
My question is, how can I combine this sound for example 'Good news' with the `MyNotification.SoundName`.
I use Delphi 10.3.3

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyNotification: TNotification;
begin
  MyNotification := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
  try
    MyNotification.Name := 'MyNotification';
    MyNotification.Title := 'Notification 01';
    // MyNotification.SoundName := how to get another sound that are installed on the smartphone 
    // for example
    MyNotification.SoundName := TPath.Combine(TPath.???, 'Good news???.mp3'); 
    MyNotification.FireDate := Now; 
    NotificationCenter1.ScheduleNotification(MyNotification);
  finally
    MyNotification.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Great thanks for any suggestions and help.

Comment: If the sound files are on the device it's: TPath.GetRingtonesPath

Comment: According to the documentation you have to set enablesound to true: MyNotification.EnableSound := True; Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If I do a test to view the files in this directory "TPath.GetRingtonesPath" nothing is displayed.

```
var
  aStrArray: TStringDynArray;
  i, icount: integer;
begin
    aStrArray := TDirectory.GetFiles(TPath.GetRingtonesPath);
    icount := High(aStrArray);
    form1.memo2.lines.add('> '+TPath.GetRingtonesPath+'<   Count='+IntToStr(icount));
    for i := 0 to icount do form1.memo2.lines.add( aStrArray[i]);
end;
```

I did another test and adding a audio file 'Beep01.mp3' to deployment

```
 assets/
```

by doing a test the file is well existing in this directory "TPath.GetPublicPath"

I try to add sound to the notification SoundName like this, but by starting the notification no sound audible appear.

```
 MyNotification.SoundName: = TPath.Combine(TPath.GetPublicPath, 'Beep01.mp3');
```

what can i do to play another tone.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the mp3 file to .\assests\internal

You can play the file using this code example assuming the name of the file is stored in the variable 'filename':

```
    uses
      Androidapi.JNI.Media;    
    var
      mp : JMediaPlayer
    begin
      mp := tjmediaplayer.Create;
mp.setdatasource(StringToJString(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(System.ioutils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath) + filename));
      mp.prepare;
      mp.start;
      // mp.release;
    end;
```

In fact you should create and release the mediaplayer outside this procedure in the forms 'oncreate' and 'ondestroy', this is why I commented out the release part in the example. Otherwise I expect the release to stop the mediaplayer immediately.

Comment: like this example, to play a sound directly this works fine.
But what I need is a schedule Notification Messages using the ScheduleNotification method like this 
`MyNotification.FireDate := Now + EncodeTime(0, 30, 0, 0);`